# Websphere app server start issues even when no EARs in it

Tags: websphere, rmi, rad, websphere-6.1

In RAD 7 I created a new server profile (using version 6.1) and tried to start this server without any projects added to it, with the intention of making sure the server starts up fine and then adding projects via the Add/Remove projects option. While I have done this many times before I have started getting this problem now:

1) Console says 'Server server1 open for e-business` but the server tab still shows that server is 'Starting...'

2) After several minutes I get the error saying server failed startup failed after 300 seconds.

3) Opening the FFDC log file shows the following exception

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [9/16/13 16:40:06:745 EDT] , key = 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException 
com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
Exception = javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
Source = com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info
probeid = 1133
Stack Dump = javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "RMIConnector" not found in context "".
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1095)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:991)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:566)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2226)
at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextImplBase._invoke(_NamingContextImplBase.java:284)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:627)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:480)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:512)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2665)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2530)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
```

4)I also see a server1_exception file with the following line in it

```
 Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
 1      1    9/16/13 16:40:06:745 EDT javax.naming.NameNotFoundException 
com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
```

------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

I do have other server profiles created for other versions of the workspace but I'm sure none of them are running while I try to run the profile in question. I noticed this started happening when I stopped one profile, then switched to another one and tried to start that up. Since then I haven't been able to start any of the profiles old or new and I keep getting this error/exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to connectivity problems between RAD and the application server. The causes of these errors are many different possible:

1. Change of credentials of the user you are trying to connect with. There should be error messages in your SystemOut.log of the server to support this.
2. Pure connectivity errors, such as the port configuration being wrong. Check which RMI/SOAP ports you are using by accessing your administrative console directly in a browser and make sure that you have the same ports configured in your RAD configuration. Try both SOAP and RMI and most important, do not trust the automatic settings (I have found them to be wrong in more than one time).